# Matlab error: Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1)

Tags: matlab

I did my best to write this code but it doesn't work, could anyone help me please

I want to plot the function uVLL, it's the approximate solution of a pde

```
    for i=1:N+2
        uVLL(i,1)= g(a+i.*h);
    end


    for i=1:N+1
        V(i,1) = g(a+(i+0.5)*h);
    end


    for i=2:N+1
        uVLL(i,2)= uVLL(i,1)- cte*(V(i,1) - V(i-1,1));
    end

    for j=3:M-1

        for i=2:N
            W(i,1) = V(i,j-1);  % I want to keep the values of the vector V(i,j-1) and change the next 
            V(i,j-1)= uVLL(i,j-1) + (W(i,1) - W(i-1,1))/h; % change the values of the vector V(i,j-1)
        end

        V(1,j-1)=V(2,j-1);
        V(N+1,j-1)=V(N,j-1);

    for i=2:N+1
        uVLL(i,j)= uVLL(i,j-1)- cte*( V(i,j-1)- V(i-1,j-1));
    end
     uVLL(1,j)= uVLL(2,j);
     uVLL(N+2,j)= uVLL(N,j);
    end
```

the error that I get

```
Index in position 2 exceeds array
bounds (must not exceed 1).

Error in VLL_CdtN (line 23)
            W(i,1) = V(i,j-1);

Error in Appel_MDF (line 24)
uVLL=VLL_CdtN(g,N,M,a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Use the debugger. What is the size of `V` before the error occurs? Unless you provide a [mre], we can't reproduce your problem ourselves.

Comment: V is a matrix i=1,2..,N+1 and j=1,....M-1, but when I write V(i,j-1) the column is fixed and I want to copy this vector to W

Comment: "V is a matrix i=1,2..,N+1..." It looks like `V` is a one-dimensional *vector*, in which case `V(i,j-1)` wouldn't make any sense (although you *might* get away with it if `i` is always 1; then it would just be sloppy coding). Again, **check** the actual size of the array during execution, don't rely on what you *think* it should be. And provide executable code if you expect us to help you debug.

Comment: Thank You, you were right, I add V=zeros(N+1,M-1); and I got my plot :))))